# Flask sqlalchemy model shared across multiple Oracle schemas

Tags: python, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy, schema

I have to create an Flask application which need to read data from multiple almost identical schemas placed on this same Oracle instance. I am able to connect to this database only by 'read_only' user.
By do this I am using blueprints.

```
project
|-warehouse01
|   -__init__.py 
|   - view.py
|-warehouse02
|   -__init__.py 
|   - view.py
|-warehouse999
|   -__init__.py 
|   - view.py
-model.py
run.py
config.py
```

Of course model for all schemas is identical

```
class Product(db.Model):
    #__table_args__ = {'schema': 'warehouse01'}
    __tablename__ = 'PRODUCTS'
    prod_no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    prod_name = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    ...
    steps = db.relationship('Shipment', backref='shipments', lazy='dynamic')

class Shipment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'SHIPMENTS'
    #__table_args__ = {'schema': 'warehouse01'}
    shipm_no = db.Column(db.Integer,  ,  primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    prod_no = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('PRODUCTS.prod_no'), nullable=False)
    customer_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('CUSTOMERS.customer_id') nullable=False)
    ...
```

Problem is that connecting by different schema (READ_ONLY) I have to declare a schema in **table_args** 
I would like to use this same model to all schemas. Obviously I do not want to create separate models for all blueprints.
Is it possible to use this same model for all schemas or redefine in blueprint a schema name?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use a factory function to create your models on the fly:

```py
def create_product_model(schema):
    class Product(db.Model):
        __table_args__ = {'schema': schema}
        __tablename__ = 'PRODUCTS'
        prod_no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
        prod_name = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
        quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
        ...
        steps = db.relationship('Shipment', backref='shipments', lazy='dynamic')

    return Product
```

Comment: this is impossible to use this approach. By using 
`def index():
    products = create_product_model('warehouse01)
    print(type(session.sess_no))
    return 'test'`

 you receiving _<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>_

Comment: to make it working i had to add `__table_args__ = {'schema': schema, 'extend_existing': True}`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a way to do this. Unfortunately a approach proposed by  @Laurent LAPORTE was not proper. It works only when I had just one class in model, and only after adding `'extend_existing': True`. Please correct me if I am wrong  but in Flask a database model is declared at application start. As schema name is a part of a class declared in `__table_args__ = {'schema': schema}`, while you would like to change the schema, SqlAlchemy treats it as try to defining new class with existing name in model registry.

My solution is to remove schema from **table_args** and setup a schema name by sql command like below:
`def estimate_schema(schema):
     db.engine.execute(f"alter session set current_schema={schema}")`

This I use before each route and it works

`def index():
    estimate_schema('warehouse01')
    ...`